# Does openHAB support the Google Assistant?

Tags: google-assistant, openhab

I've been considering using [openHAB](http://www.openhab.org/) recently as my home automation system, but I'd like to connect a Google Home to it so I can control the system with my voice.

It looks like openHAB [support Amazon Alexa through the `openhab-alexa` skill](https://github.com/openhab/openhab-alexa), so with an Echo I could issue voice commands and receive simple voice messages, but I'd like to use a Google Home instead.

I've checked the [Supported Technologies](http://www.openhab.org/features/supported-technologies.html) page on the openHAB website, but it looks like there's nothing there for the Google Home/Assistant. **Is it possible to connect my Google Home to openHAB?** If possible, I'd like to connect directly, but I would be happy with connecting it through a different service if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, from this [forum post](https://community.openhab.org/t/google-home-support/16252/3) that you can use [ha-bridge](https://github.com/bwssytems/ha-bridge) which masquerades as a Philips Hue bridge, permitting it to consume the basic lighting commands. If you have Hue devices, you need a real Hue bridge behind ha-bridge.

Since this supports Google Home, you're able to implement voice command, but potentially some limitations to the scope of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but still active, so it deserves an updated answer.

Yes, OpenHAB 3 is fully integrated with Google Assistant via their myopenHAB.org cloud bridge.

https://www.openhab.org/docs/ecosystem/google-assistant/#google-assistant-action